# Ошибка переполнения буфера в си

Tags: c

Дан бинарный файл вещественных чисел, содержащий элементы
прямоугольной матрицы размера N на M, причём значения N и M
хранятся в первых двух элементах файла. Создать новый бинарный
файл того же формата, содержащий транспонированную матрицу

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    #include <locale.h>
    
    int main() {
    
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    
        FILE* fp;
        int N[2];
    
        if (fopen_s(&fp, "arr.bin", "rb") != 0) {
            printf("Ошибка открытия файла!");
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    
        fread(N, sizeof(int), 2, fp);
    
        float** a = (float**)malloc(N[0] * sizeof(float*));
        for (int i = 0; i < N[0]; i++)
            a[i] = (float*)malloc(N[1] * sizeof(float)); 
    
        for (int i = 0; i < N[0]; i++)
            fread(a[i], sizeof(float), N[1], fp);
    
        if (fclose(fp) != 0)
            printf("Ошибка закрытия файла");
    
        if (fopen_s(&fp, "arr.bin", "wb") != 0) {
            printf("Ошибка открытия файла!");
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    
        for (int j = 0; j < N[1]; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < N[0]; i++)
                fwrite(&a[i][j], sizeof(float), 1, fp); 
    
    
        for (int i = 0; i < N[0]; i++) {
            free(a[i]);
        }
        free(a);
    
        if (fclose(fp) != 0) 
            printf("Ошибка закрытия файла");
    
        system("pause");
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: `The behavior is undefined if the value of the pointer stream is used after fclose returns. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считывать динамическую матрицу из файла нужно построчно, т.к. для статической матрицы память под элементы выделяется прямолинейно, но не для динамической.

Вы пытаетесь поместить `N[0] * N[1]` элементов в `a`, то есть в первую строку матрицы, в случае со статической матрицей ошибки не было бы т.к. в памяти все элементы идут друг за другом и вторая группа из `N[1]` элементов поместилась бы  уже на вторую строчку матрицы, но для динамической матрицы вы выделяете для каждой строчки память отдельно (для этого пишется цикл for)

По этому вместо:

```
fread(a, sizeof(int), N[0] * N[1], fp);
```

Нужно писать это:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N[0]; i++)
    fread(a[i], sizeof(float), N[1], fp);
```

P.s. надеюсь понятно объяснил

А так же у вас установлен не правильный режим открытия файла во втором случае.

В место `rw` (read, write) вам нужно `wb` (write, binary)

Comment: Кстати, если речь в задании о *вещественных числах*, то почему под элементы матрицы выбран **тип int?**

Comment: @avp автор кода так решил :)

Comment: Так он не ведает, что творит. Наставьте его в своем ответе на путь истинный

Comment: @avp по комментариям поймет я думаю

Comment: Если ему нужно, то должен понять.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков    выделение памяти для динамического массива происходит после следующей строчки

'''
fread(N, sizeof(int), 2, fp);

'''

Как и нужно через цикл for

Comment: fread(N, sizeof(int), 2, fp); берет из файла количество строк и столбцов

Comment: @дмитрийлевшенков ну как бы я знаю, но причем тут это?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков  у меня ошибка возникает в этой строке a[i] = (float*)malloc(N[1] * sizeof(float)); Переполнение буфера при записи в "a":  доступный для записи объем равен "N[0]*sizeof(float *)" байт, однако записать можно только "8" байт.

Comment: Она возникает при создании дин.массива

Comment: Я к тому, что ваш ответ не решает мою проблему

Comment: @дмитрийлевшенков ну хорошо, проверьте через дебагер считываются ли правильно `N`? Лично у меня все работает отлично. У вас же может скорей всего тогда в бинарном файле проблема. И то что вы пишите "_Переполнение буфера..._" это предупреждение а не ошибка.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков нет, в N пишутся гораздо большие значения

Comment: Да, это предупреждение, но у меня на нем программа ломается

Comment: @дмитрийлевшенков ага вы везде добавили `float`,  а зачем? У вас `N` это размерность матрицы это точно не вещественное число. `fread(N, sizeof(int), 2, fp);` напишите вместо `float`

Comment: @ПавелЕриков все равно проблема осталась

Comment: @дмитрийлевшенков у вас точно правильно заполненный бинарный файл?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков я его заполнил через фар такими значениями 3 4 1.2 2.4 /n
3.4 3.4 2.7 1.9 /n
4.4 4.5 4.9 1.8

Comment: @дмитрийлевшенков а как вы конкретно записываете эти числа в файл? Открывая в режиме `wb` и через `fwrite`?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков , беру числа из массива a (по столбцам) и записываю в файл в строку, я только немного не понимаю как сделать записать не в одну строку

Comment: Открывая в режиме wb и через fwrite? ДА

Comment: @дмитрийлевшенков в общем выкладывайте код, так проще будет. На данном этапе не имею понятия в чем у вас проблема.

Comment: @дмитрийлевшенков ну что вы будете выкладывать код как вы заполняете бинарный файл? И да хотел сказать, что менять содержимое вопроса на то, что вы узнали из ответа, не есть правильно! И да мне интересно почему вы все поменяли, кроме `fread(a, sizeof(float), N[0] * N[1], fp);`?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков как заполняю изначально или после прочтения файла?

Comment: @ПавелЕриков И да мне интересно почему вы все поменяли, кроме fread(a, sizeof(float), N[0] * N[1], fp);?   
так там же вещественный массив

Comment: @дмитрийлевшенков Как вы изначально заполняете файл. Я имею в виду, что вы так и оставили строчку с `N[0] * N[1]`, что не правильно. И не меняйте уже вопрос дополняя его тем, что прочитали в ответе. Получается я ответил на вопрос, в котором и так все нормально.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков я переделал как вы и показывали, но теперь вылезло предупреждение, Чтение недопустимых данных из а

Comment: @дмитрийлевшенков в общем выложите в вопросе вообще весь код, что у вас есть сейчас.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков выложил

Comment: @дмитрийлевшенков вы просто убрали комментарии и добавили опять токи, то что я написал в своем ответе. Вот [полный код](https://pastebin.com/dwwwp4Cb) в итоге вы должны получить файл, в котором будет `1 3 5 2 4 6`.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков я неправильно работал с бинарным файлом, я понял это сейчас, когда вместо 1 3 5 2 4 6 у меня читается просто квадратики

Comment: @дмитрийлевшенков ага то есть сейчас все нормально? Если да и вам помог мой ответ, то пожалуйста отметьте его как "Правильный ответ" нажав на галочку слева от ответа

Comment: @ПавелЕриков да, спасибо